# How to merge two files with a common key in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files k1 and k2 and I am trying to merge both files based on the common key 'Name of Book'.

k1

```
John | Dreaming of Day | IEEEJournal
Akon | Dreaming of Night | ACMJournal
```

k2

```
Dreaming of Day | Fiction
Dreaming of Night | Non-Fiction
```

kout: Should merge based on Name of Book ie `Dreaming of Day` and `Dreaming of Night`

```
John | Fiction | IEEEJournal
Akon | Non-Fiction | ACMJournal
```

I have written below awk script:

```
 awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}($1$2 in a && $3=$3"|"a[$1$2])' k1 k2
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `gawk` solution using array of arrays

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS=" \\| "; OFS=" | "}
    FNR==NR{d[$2][1] = $1; d[$2][3] = $3; next}
    $1 in d{print d[$1][1], $2, d[$1][3]}
    ' k1 k2
```

It isn't `awk` solution, using `sed` and `join`

```
join <(sed 's/ | /|/g' k1) <(sed 's/ | /|/g' k2) -1 2 -2 1 -t'|' -o '1.1 2.2 1.3' | sed 's/|/ | /g'
```

you get

```
John | Fiction | IEEEJournal
Akon | Non-Fiction | ACMJournal
```

**EDIT AWK VERSION**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" [|] "; OFS=" | "}
    FNR==NR{d1[$2] = $1; d3[$2] = $3; next}
    $1 in d1{print d1[$1], $2, d3[$1]}
    ' k1 k2
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I am getting error awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 BEGIN{FS=" \\| "; OFS=" | "} >>>  FNR==NR{d[$2][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Could you show me the error, what version of awk do you use?

Comment: awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version
awk version 20070501

Comment: This version does not support arary of arrays, I already fix it

Comment: I downloaded: El Capitan (10.11) gawk-4.1.3-0.pkg

Comment: i fixed `awk` version problem in post

Comment: I have very little idea about sed. Do i need to use sed as well for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct `sed` arguments with

```
sed 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)/s# \1#\2 #/' k2
```

These arguments can be used in another sed command by

```
sed -f <(sed 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)/s# \1#\2 #/' k2) k1
```

Comment: Thanks Walter for your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
join -12 -21  -t\|  k1 k2
Dreaming of Day |John | IEEEJournal| Fiction
Dreaming of Night |Akon | ACMJournal| Non-Fiction
```

Caveats:

- keys are similarly ordered
- since not keying off default first column, whitespace matters. So trim or pad your keys to match

to omit the key from the output

```
join -12 -21  -t\|  k1 k2 | cut -f2- -d\|
John | IEEEJournal| Fiction
Akon | ACMJournal| Non-Fiction
```

Comment: Thanks Tomc for your answer as well. +1 !